# UISearchBar textDidChange, searchtext variable unusable with rangeOfString?

Tags: string, swift, uisearchbar

I have been searching for hours and no solution in sight... I am filtering an array of custom objects using the text typed into a UISearchBar to change the data in the tableview below. 
After a bit of debugging, ive pin pointed the source of my troubles:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    var temp = "c"
    FilterResults = SearchResults.filter {
    return $0.Username.rangeOfString(temp) != nil
    }

    }
```

here is my trouble: If I used a temp that is explicitely defined as above , where temp = "c", it happily matches all the user names that have a c in it! The issue arises when instead of using temp, I used the variable searchText, in that cases it never EVER matches with anything! I checked and searchText is not null, in fact I printed out searchText in tests and it printed out a normal string (Based on what is typed in the search bar), but for some crazy reason, if I use the searchText variable inside the .rangeOfString method, it always returns false! Why is that? Ive also used searchBar.text and it gave me the same troubles... I am completely lost and frustrated. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works.

```
var searchList = [String]()
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText!)
let array = (searchList as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate) as! [String]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I didn't realize that the rangeOfString search is case sensitive!